# Swift 3.0 OptionSet Bit Test

Tags: swift, optionsettype

With the following OptionSet:

```
struct StatusOptions : OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int
    static let CountdownDuration0 = StatusOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let CountdownDuration1 = StatusOptions(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let CountdownDuration2 = StatusOptions(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let CountdownDuration3 = StatusOptions(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    static let CountdownDuration4 = StatusOptions(rawValue: 1 << 4)
    static let CountdownDuration5 = StatusOptions(rawValue: 1 << 5)
    static let HomeMode = StatusOptions(rawValue: 1 << 6)
    static let AwayMode = StatusOptions(rawValue: 1 << 7)

    static let Disarmed: StatusOptions = []
    static let ArmedHome: StatusOptions = .HomeMode
    static let ArmedAway: StatusOptions = .AwayMode
    static let ArmedBoth: StatusOptions = [.HomeMode, .AwayMode]
    static let ArmingCountdown: StatusOptions = [.CountdownDuration0, .CountdownDuration1, .CountdownDuration2, .CountdownDuration3, .CountdownDuration4, .CountdownDuration5]
}
```

How do I compare a byte

```
var statusFlags: UInt8 = 0b00000000
```

To the Options?

The following is what I'd think would work, but causes a playground error:

```
if (statusFlags & .Disarmed) {
    print("Disarmed")
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `.Disarmed` is zero, you say:

```
if statusFlags == .Disarmed
```

or even more simply:

```
if statusFlags.isEmpty
```

For other values, you say, e.g.:

```
if statusFlags.contains(.CountdownDuration3)
```

That is the whole *point* of an OptionSet. You use *set* operations, not arithmetic bit operations.

But for this to work, so that you can take advantage of OptionSet's yummy goodness, `statusFlags` needs to *be* a StatusOptions. You can do that by way of the StatusOptions `rawValue:` initializer:

```
let statusFlags = StatusOptions(rawValue:0b00000000)
statusFlags.isEmpty // true
```

(Note that in Swift 3, a zero bitmask like `.Disarmed` probably wouldn't even be used. Zero is just an empty set.)